# How can I create a Visual Studio like notification panel using WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image]

But i'm unable to figure out what controls i need to use. All i want is a notification panel for each notification with a title and little description which when clicked, open up the details of the corresponding notification. 
What i can't figure out is, how can i generate such notification panels with title and a little description at runtime for an unknown number of notifications.

Comment: Add a form to your project with a textbox to contain messages.  Change setting on textbox to multiline.

Comment: It can be done that way, but I'm trying to do something different. I want individual panels for all the notifications so they can be clicked. If all the notification go into a single textbox, users won't be able to click each notification individually and check out the details

Comment: The best option is probably to create a user control to represent a notification (row). Then all you need is a scrollable control like panel or flowlayoutpanel.

Comment: Agree with @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, see [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) and [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: What did you end up doing?